# Simple Python Question w/ List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.6

Why is this wrong? I had ran it before and it worked but for some reason now it isn't running. It's very easy and I'm a beginner so I'm struggling to figure it out.

```
def checkTemp(x):
  if x == 0:
    return 0
  elif x > 32:
    return 'above'
  elif x == 32:
    return 'freezing'
  elif x < 32:
    return 'below'


def aboveBelowFreeze(tempList):
    '''
    Given a list of temperatures, return a list of strings
    that say 'above', 'below', or 'freezing', depending
    on whether the temperature was above 32, below 32, or
    equal to 32. Create a helper function if you need it.
    '''
    return ([checkTemp(x) for x in tempList])
```

Comment: Are you calling `aboveBelowFreeze` anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I am seeing no issue except returning '0' instead of 0

Comment: How is this "not running"?  I added a simple test case, and it worked fine.  Is the problem that you deleted your main program, so that you never call the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be working fine as long as you are calling the aboveBelowFreeze function with a list input. Having something like this outside the functions with no indent:

```
print(aboveBelowFreeze([40,2]))
```